# Writing multiple lists to CSV only outputs 1 line

Tags: python, list, csv

I have several lists of various lengths that I am trying to export to CSV so they can be called up again later when the program is launched again. Everytime I try the following, it only outputs a single line of data to the csv:

```
export = [solutions, fedata, bbcom, fenxt, ten_99, ten_99links]
with open('test.csv','w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    # writer.writerow([<header row>]) #uncomment this and put header, if you want header row , if not leave it commented.
    for x in zip(*export):
        writer.writerow(x)
```

some of the lists currently only have 1 item in them, but I am trying to basically make a CSV be a database for this program as we will be adding more to the lists as it is expanded. Any help is appreciated, I am really banging my head against the wall here.

I tried the pasted code but it only outputs a single line of data

Comment: The `zip` function stops when the shortest iterable is exhausted, so if any of the lists in `export` is shorter than the others, it will not be fully written to the CSV file. Rather than using the `zip` approach, try using a second for loop to iterate over `export` and write row by row, and see if the problem persists.

Comment: @LahcenYAMOUN or [itertools.zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)

Comment: @Fractalism yes indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want every item to be on a newline or every list on a newline?

If you want an empty line between the prints then you can remove the `newline=''`

Try this:

```python
with open('test.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(export)
```